# LinqToExcel parsing pivoted data

Tags: c#, excel, linq

I've been trying to parse an excel file using the [LinqToExcel](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel) library. My excel file has the following "design":

```
Property1   |   Property2   |   HasExtraProperty1   |   HasExtraProperty2   |  HasExtraProperty3
------------|---------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-------------------
   foo      |     bar       |          yes          |          yes          |         no
   barfoo   |     foobar    |          no           |          no           |         yes
   barbar   |     foofoo    |          no           |          yes          |         no
```

---

An abstraction of my model looks like this:

```
class MyModel
{
        List<ExtraProperties> extraProperties;
        String property1;
        String property2;
}
```

I used the mappings from the library to easily map the (in this example) String properties to the columns. This all works fluently, but now I'm stuck parsing the other properties. Only the the extra properties with a "yes" should be added to the list. Any ideas on how to solve this with a linq query?

Note 1: For future-proofness, the number of extra properties should be able to vary.

Note 2: I've considered using another library, but I'm already using LinqToExcel somewhere in my project, and I'm trying to keep the dependencies at a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the easiest solution was to abandon the convenient mapping provided by LinqToExcel, and just looping through every columnname/row.

```
IExcelQueryFactory fact = new ExcelQueryFactory(path);
var query = from r in fact.Worksheet(0)
            select r;
IList<MyModel> models = new List<MyModel>();
foreach(var row in query){
    MyModel m = new MyModel();
    foreach(String colName in MyColMapping.Keys){
        p.GetType().GetProperty(colName).SetValue(p, row[ColMapping[colName]]);
    }
    foreach(ExtraProperty p in PMapping.Keys){
        if(row[PMapping[p]].Equals("yes"))
            m.ExtraProperties.Add(p);
    }
    models.add(m);
}
```

Note: ColMapping is a dictionary which maps names of excel-columns with model-properties. PMapping is a dictionary which maps excel-columns with the right object of the extra properties.